# Symfony FOSUserBundle does not authenticate users and does not advise bad credentials

Tags: symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle, symfony-forms

I have installed  `FOSUserBundle`, I see that's active and my login page is ok too. The problem comes out when I try to login as an user. If I insert wrong credentials, nothing happens, I'm redirected to the login page without signalling "bad credentials" as usual. If I insert right user information, I'm redirected to the homepage and I'm not logged in, in the  `Symfony` toolbar I'm authenticated as anonymous and I have only an AnonymousToken.

This is my security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

This is part of my config.yml:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: ***\***Bundle\Entity\User
```

In Symfony log, I can read:

```
security.INFO: User "sampleuser" has been authenticated successfully [] []
```

but this is apparently not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the solution to my problem. The cause was    `LswMemcacheBundle` ,
I have installed `memcached` php extension, but i haven't run `memcache` on my system. I've run it and afterwards all login/logout functionalities have started working correctly.